# How to Save selected radio button value into custom object from Visualforce page

Tags: salesforce-lightning

Need to save the selected radio button value into custom object.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwOcP.png)

`
If I select "Excellent" radio button and click submit button. Need to save Excellent value into custom object. But my code is not save the value into custom object. Below is my code and please suggest where i am doing wrong.

1. VF Code:

---

```
<apex:page  controller="RadioBtn_table_Apex" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="true" applyBodyTag="false">
<style>
    .fswrapper{
            width:800px;
            margin:0 auto;
            border:3CCF4E 30px;
        }
    
    .headerTitle
        {
            font-family:arial,sans-serif;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:600;
            color: #fff!important;
            text-align:left;
            text-transform:UPPERCASE;
            background:#4e75a3;
            Padding:10px;
            display:block;
            margin:0;
            
        }
    
    input[type=radio] {margin-left: 40px;}
    .radioClass {margin-left: 5%;}
    
    .big {line-height: 2.8;}

</style>
    <apex:form styleClass="fswrapper" id="frm">
        <head>
            <apex:slds />
        </head>
        <center>
            <img src="{!$Resource.ForceDotCom}"/>           
        </center>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <h1 class="headerTitle"> Application Feedback </h1>
                 <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                      <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!savefeedback}" reRender="frm"/>
                      <apex:commandButton value="Exit" action="{!feedbackexit}" reRender="frm"/>
                 </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:actionRegion >

                <Table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" columns="0" > 
                    <tr >
                        <td colspan="5" class="fieldLabel">                     
                            <p style="font-size: 20px;">
                               <b> How likely are you with our Application </b>
                            </p>      
                            
                            <!--<apex:selectRadio id="selectRb" value="{!selectedAnswer}" immediate="true"> -->
                            <apex:selectRadio id="selectRb" value="{!ratobj.Application_Rating__c}">
                                <apex:selectOption value="{!items}"/>                                 
                            </apex:selectRadio>
                                
                        </td>
                     </tr> 
                 </Table>                           
           </apex:actionRegion> 
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

### APEX Code :

```
public  class RadioBtn_table_Apex 
{
    
    public RB_Rating__c ratobj{get;set;} 
    public string SelectedAnswer {get;set;}
    
    public RadioBtn_table_Apex()
    {
      ratobj = new RB_Rating__c();        
    }
    
    public pagereference savefeedback()
    {
       
        insert ratobj;
       
       return Auth.SessionManagement.FinishLoginflow('/'+ratobj.Id);
    }
    
    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
    options.add(new SelectOption('Excellent','Excellent')); 
    options.add(new SelectOption('Great','Great')); 
    options.add(new SelectOption('Good','Good')); 
    options.add(new SelectOption('Medium','Medium'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Poor','Poor'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Very Bad','Very Bad'));
    return options; 
}
    
    public pagereference feedbackexit()
    {
        
       return Auth.SessionManagement.FinishLoginflow('/');
    }

}
```

Please suggest and where i am doing wrong.

Thanks

```
i am trying to save my selected radio button values into custom object
```